# NullReferenceException при попытке получить List.Count

Tags: unity3d, list

## Описание

У меня есть небольшой скрипт.
Этот скрипт создаёт локальную базу данных и имеет некоторые основные части такие как -
1. Список `Students.Data`, в котором все данные о студентах.
2. Функция `Students.Save()`, который сохраняет список `Students.Data` в памяти устройства.
3. Функция `Students.Load()`, который загружает данные и присваивает их списку `Students.Data`.
4. Функция `RefreshStudentsList()`, который обновляет список студентов показанных на экране.

Проблема у меня в том что при вызове функции `RefreshStudentsList()` получаю ошибку `NullReferenceException` в строке `for (int i = 0; i < Students.Data.Count; i++)` видимо потому что `Students.Data.Count` равен null. Попробовал исправить всеми возможными способами человечества. Ошибка исчезает если первый раз запускаем программу, а если уже есть сохранённые данные, то появляется.

---

## Скрипт

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Global: MonoBehaviour
{
    private class Container
    {
        public List<Student> Students;
        public Container(List<Student> Input)
        {
            Students = Input;
        }
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        Students.Load();
        StudentsPrefab = NonStaticStudentsPrefab;
    }

    //------------------------------ start of Student ------------------------------
    public class Student
    {
        public string Name, Surname, About;
        public int Sex;
    }
    public static class Students
    {
        public static List<Student> Data = new List<Student>(); //Список студентов
        public static void Save() //Сохранение
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Students", JsonUtility.ToJson(new Container(Data)));
        }
        public static void Load() //Загрузка
        {
            if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Students"))
            {
                Data = new List<Student>();
            }
            else
            {
                Data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Container>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Students")).Students;
            }
        }
    }

    public GameObject NonStaticStudentsPrefab;
    static GameObject StudentsPrefab;
    public static void RefreshStudentsList() //Обновление
    {
        GameObject StudentsParent = Functions.Find("Content (Students)");
        for (int i = 0; i < StudentsParent.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            Destroy(StudentsParent.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Students.Data.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject StudentCopy = Instantiate(StudentsPrefab, StudentsParent.transform);
        }
    }
    //------------------------------ end of Student ------------------------------
}
```

---

## Вопрос

*Почему после загрузки постоянно появляется эта ошибка и **как можно это исправить?***

Comment: `int Sex`... сколько их там? 56? `Боевой вертолёт` тоже есть? =D

Comment: @Yaroslav их там двое: мужчина - 0, женщина- 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> видимо потому что `Students.Data.Count` равен null.

→ `Students.Data` - равно `null`. А `null` мы получаем потому что данные не сохраняются. Чтобы сохранение прошло успешно надо сериализовать класс `Student`.
Исправленный код выглядит таким →

```cs
using System;

...

[Serializable]
public class Student
{
    public string Name, Surname, About;
    public int Sex;
}

...

public static void Load() //Загрузка
{
    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Students"))
    {
        Data = new List<Student>();
    }
    else
    {
        Data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Container(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Students")).Students;
        if (Data == null)
            Data = new List<Student>();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. А не лучше будет вот так - `if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Students") || Data == null)`?. 2 У меня данные не сохраняются после этого.

Comment: @Арман Нет, не лучше. Проблема в сохранении (а скорее, в восстановлении) данных. Я не помню, каким условиям должен удовлетворять восстанавливаемый объект. Что-нибудь про конструктор без параметров.

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш ответ помог мне понять в чём причина ошибки. Можно я буду немного редактировать ваш ответ или же написать новый?

Comment: @Арман Конечно, редактируйте.